# Improve find and replace string in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have string like this

```
 val message = "Hello, How are you? My Name is <b>Xyz</b>. <b>Abc</b> your next score will be 100 to win the game."
```

I want to find string between `<b>` and `</b>`. So I make a pattern like this

```
private const val BOLD_PATTERN = "<b>(.*?)</b>"
```

I tried to search it and got the result. Now I want to remove this `<b>` and `</b>` from my main string. I did this without any problem

```
private const val BOLD_PATTERN = "<b>(.*?)</b>"
fun main() {
    val message = "Hello, How are you? My Name is <b>Xyz</b>. <b>Abc</b> your next score will be 100 to win the game."
    val itemList = findAndGetBoldList(message)
    val filterMessage = message.replace("<b>", "").replace("</b>", "")
    itemList.forEach { println("Bold part is :- $it") }
    println(filterMessage)
}

fun findAndGetBoldList(message: String): List<String> {
    return BOLD_PATTERN
        .toRegex()
        .findAll(message)
        .map {
            it.value.replace("<b>", "").replace("</b>", "")
        }
        .toList()
}
```

**Output**

```
Bold part is :- Xyz
Bold part is :- Abc
Hello, How are you? My Name is Xyz. Abc your next score will be 100 to win the game.
```

My question is can we improved this idiomatic way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** `private const val BOLD_PATTERN = "<b>(.*?)</b>"`

You get better performance by compiling a constant pattern once, rather than compiling the same thing every time you call a function. So:

```
private const val BOLD_REGEX = "<b>(.*?)</b>".toRegex()
```

However, you don't want to have the tags as part of the match, so you can leave them out by using [positive lookbehind and positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Also, the tags are case-insensitive. Use the following regex and you can iterate through your matches without having to remove the tags:

```
private val BOLD_REGEX = "(?<=<b>).*?(?=</b>)".toRegex(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
...
fun findAndGetBoldList(message: String): List<String> {
    return BOLD_REGEX
        .findAll(message)
        .map {
            it.value
        }
        .toList()
}
```

**2.** `val filterMessage = message.replace("<b>", "").replace("</b>", "")`

Again, you should filter based on case-insensitive matches. You can also do this with a single call to replace:

```
private val REMOVE_BOLD_TAG_REGEX = "</?b>".toRegex(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
...
    val filterMessage = message.replace(REMOVE_BOLD_TAG_REGEX, "")
```

**The code in full:**

```
private val BOLD_REGEX = "(?<=<b>).*?(?=</b>)".toRegex(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
private val REMOVE_BOLD_TAG_REGEX = "</?b>".toRegex(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)

fun main() {
    val message = "Hello, How are you? My Name is <b>Xyz</b>. <b>Abc</b> your next score will be 100 to win the game."
    val itemList = findAndGetBoldList(message)
    val filterMessage = message.replace(REMOVE_BOLD_TAG_REGEX, "")
    itemList.forEach { println("Bold part is :- $it") }
    println(filterMessage)
}

fun findAndGetBoldList(message: String): List<String> {
    return BOLD_REGEX
        .findAll(message)
        .map {
            it.value
        }
        .toList()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can simplify your method somewhat.

```
 fun String.extractBoldItems(): Pair<String, List<String>> {
    val boldItems = mutableListOf<String>()
    val filteredMessage = replace(BOLD_PATTERN.toRegex()) {
        boldItems.add(it.groupValues[1])
        it.value.replace(Regex("<(/)?b>"), "")
    }
    return filteredMessage to boldItems
}
```

Usage example:

```
 fun main() {
        val message = "Hello, How are you? My Name is <b>Xyz</b>. <b>Abc</b> your next score will be 100 to win the game."

        val (filterMessage, itemList) = message.extractBoldItems()

        itemList.forEach { println("Bold part is :- $it") }
        println(filterMessage)
    }
```

Comment: what does `t.groupValues[1]` do?

Comment: About [groupValues](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/group-values.html)

Comment: 404 when opening the link

Comment: I added an extra character to the link, check again

Comment: your answer is removing the  main word from the main list.

Comment: It doesn't delete, but replaces them with an empty string. This is happening on line 5. 
But you can add code like this 
`it.value.replace(Regex("<(/)?b>"), "") `

and it will work.

Comment: @KotlinLearner
I have edited the main answer, check it

Comment: perfect it works. Can you please explain this part `replace(Regex("<(/)?b>"), "")` ?

Comment: `replace(Regex("<(/)?b>"), "")  `

replace - this is a function to [replace](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) in Kotlin

Regex - [class for regular expression](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/)

Comment: Thanks for regex. I mean what does it mean this expression `<(/)?b>`?

Comment: This regex removes substrings <b> and </b>.